# iOS Developer Portal : Cannot add or edit app ids and profiles (greyed out)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am suddenly unable to add or edit app ids and provisioning profiles 
in my Apple iOS Developer portal

This has never happened before. Is anyone familiar with this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually the case when your user permissions do not allow you to add/remove certificates and provisioning profiles.
Please check whether you're **admin** and not **member** on the People tab.

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I could login into the apple developer portal and create certificates but was unable to create new app ids or new profiles.

1. First I had to enable two factor authentication for my developer id.
2. Although my developer id already had developer permissions assigned to it and "Access to certificates, identifiers & profiles" was checked I still couldn't create new profiles. So I had to go to iTunes connect and also add app manager to the apple id roles.

[image: Itunes Connect Screen]

I arrived at this solution by trial and error, I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Much prefered solution as often clients don't really want to make developers full admins.